# UIBarButtonSystemItem equivalent in Android?

Tags: java, android, icons

Coming from an iPhone world,

Is there an equivalent of system icons, for example, the add or search icons in the options menu of Contacts. This would save developers time (and in some cases, money) if they could use the system icons used by Android. If this is not possible, is a site available where developers can download icons for android instead of using Photoshop or GIMP to make their own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some examples as well as psd templates at the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html).